# GLib API to convert hexadecimal string to ASCII string?

Tags: c, string, hex, ascii, glib

I cannot believe there is no API to do this in GLib, for now I have only found people doing their own conversion, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa) and [here (function named "decode")](http://linuxfirmwarekit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins.c). I would really like to find a way to do this in a simple GLib call, but if there is no way, the above methods don't work for me because the former is C++ (I'm using C/GObject) and the latter doesn't seem to work perfectly (I'm having problems with the length of the result).

TIA

Comment: Could you clarify "doesn't seem to work perfectly (I'm having problems with the length of the result)"?

Comment: You work from the assumption that this is a common task.  It is not, users of your program are not typically skilled or able to enter hex strings.  Binary to hex is a bit more common, your debugger knows how to do that.  Step away from the machine for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is a bit uncommon.  If you have a short enough hex string, you can prefix it with `0x` and use `strtoll()`.  But for arbitrary length strings, here is a C function:

```
char *hex_to_string(const char *input)
{
    char a;
    size_t i, len;
    char *retval = NULL;
    if (!input) return NULL;

    if((len = strlen(input)) & 1) return NULL;

    retval = (char*) malloc(len >> 1);
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i ++)
    {
        a = toupper(input[i]);
        if (!isxdigit(a)) break;
        if (isdigit(a)) a -= '0';
        else a = a - 'A' + '\10';

        if (i & 1) retval[i >> 1] |= a;
        else retval[i >> 1] = a<<4;
    }
    if (i < len)
    {
        free(retval);
        retval = NULL;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: `retval` may not be null character terminated and then does not point to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no 100% sure what you mean by "hexadecimal string" but may be [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519084/how-to-convert-binary-to-hexadecimal-string-in-c-glib) will be of some help.