# How to convert CString to UCHAR array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, cstring

I have a cstring object str = "5043", now i want to convert to Hex and put it in UCHAR array like

```
UCHAR sample[2];
Sample[0] = 0X50 
Sample[1] = 0X43
```

How can i do this? please advice me

Comment: This might have already been answered in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa

Comment: As a possibility for widening the scope of this question, "cstring object str" -> "string".  "UCHAR" -> "unsigned char", then just leave this as a C++ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan the hex values directly from the string using `sscanf()`, something like below:

```
UCHAR sample[2];
for ( int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2 ; i++) {
    sscanf( (str.substr(i*2,2)).c_str(), "%hx", &sample[i]);
}
```

`h` is for short and `x` is for hexadecimal obviously.

Also, this assumes that the `UCHAR` array is declared to be half as large as the `string` size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [strol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)?  It seems a little low tech, but should do the trick.  Don't forget to pass 16 as the base...

You'll need to combine it with a little bit shifting and bitwise anding to split the result into exactly what you require, but that should be straightforward.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Actually, i have already got converted value but i just need to update to UCHAR variable

Comment: Hmm, in that case, I think you need a different question!  i.e.  How do I split an integer into two bytes?  (For a sixteen bit value) You probably need to right shift 8 bits for the high byte and bitwise and (&) with 255 for the low byte.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code simpler, you may use an union, e.g.

```
    union
    {
    UCHAR char_val[2];
    long long_val;
    };

    CString str = "5043";
    long_val = strtol(str.GetString(), nullptr, 16);
    // use char_val here
```