# How to pack a hexadecimal value in an unsigned char variable in a C program?

Tags: c, hex, packing

I have a hexadecimal value `"F69CF355B6231FDBD91EB1E22B61EA1F"` in a string and I am using this value in my program by hardcoding the value in an unsigned char variable like this:
`unsigned char a[] = { 0xF6 ,0x9C ,0xF3 ,0x55 ,0xB6 ,0x23 ,0x1F ,0xDB ,0xD9 ,0x1E ,0xB1 ,0xE2 ,0x2B ,0x61 ,0xEA ,0x1F};`
Is there any function or any other method by which I can take the value from a string and put it into an unsigned variable in the hexadecimal format by packing it?

Comment: Presumably you meaan `unsigned char a[]`, not `unsigned char a`.

Comment: I do not think that there are some functions. Why don't you want to create your own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn a hex string into an unsigned char array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221170/how-to-turn-a-hex-string-into-an-unsigned-char-array)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int hctoi(const char h){
    if(isdigit(h))
        return h - '0';
    else
        return toupper(h) - 'A' + 10;
}

int main(void){
    const char cdata[]="F69CF355B6231FDBD91EB1E22B61EA1F";
    unsigned char udata[(sizeof(cdata)-1)/2];
    const char *p;
    unsigned char *up;

    for(p=cdata,up=udata;*p;p+=2,++up){
        *up = hctoi(p[0])*16 + hctoi(p[1]);
    }

    {   //check code
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<sizeof(udata);++i)
            printf("%02X", udata[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate a hexadecimal value in a string into a value using `sscanf`. If you want an array of values, then you could write a function to split up the input string into two character segments and use `sscanf` to convert each piece. (I haven't done C for an eternity so I don't know if that's a good way to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

If it's for 32 single hex-values (16 bytes, 128bit) only then you might take look at the methods provided by `libuuid`.

`libuuid` is part of the [`e2fsprogs`](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) package. Anyhow some linux distros, Debian for example, ship `libuuid` as a [separate package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libuuid1). To use the Debian package for your developement you also need to look [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/uuid-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242506/how-to-convert-cstring-to-uchar-array/10242834#10242834) for doing this stuff in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) using `sscanf()`.

For [c](/questions/tagged/c), it would be something like this:

```
char *str           = "F69CF355B6231FDBD91EB1E22B61EA1F";
char substr[3]      = "__";    
unsigned char *a    = NULL;    
len                 = strlen(str);
a                   = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*(len/2)+1);
for (  i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
    substr[0]       = str[i*2];
    substr[1]       = str[i*2 + 1];
    sscanf( substr, "%hx", &a[i] );
}
free(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce auxiliary functions `data_length` and `data_get` to easily iterate over your data.  The following program dumps unpacked unsigned chars on `stdout`, one per line:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

/* htoi(H)
    Return the value associated to the hexadecimal digit H. */
int
htoi(char h)
{
  int a = -1;
  if(isdigit(h))
  {
    a = h - '0';
  }
  else
  {
    a = toupper(h) - 'A' + 10;
  }
  return a;
}

/* data_length(D)
    The length of the data stored at D. */
int
data_length(const char* d)
{
  return strlen(d) / 2;
}

/* data_get(D, K)
    Return the K-th unsigned char located encoded in d. */
unsigned char
data_get(const char *d, int k)
{
  return htoi(d[2*k]) * 0x10 +
    htoi((d+1)[2*k]);
}

int
main()
{
    const char cdata[]="F69CF355B6231FDBD91EB1E22B61EA1F";
    for(int i = 0; i < data_length(cdata); ++i)
    {
      printf("0x%02hhx\n", data_get(cdata, i));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```