# Parsing hexadecimal numbers into array

Tags: c

I have a variable `char* etag="8a964ee2a5e88be344f36c22562a6486";`.

How can I convert this into an array of `byte`, where `byte` is actually `typedef unsigned char byte`?

Comment: It is hex already, just as a string. What type were you thinking of storing it in? It's a tad long for a `unsigned long long` even

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa?

Comment: @Jay the answers there are all C++, but this is tagged C

Comment: @Jay no - the other question is for C++ not C

Comment: I want to store it as a `byte[16]` type, where `byte` is actually `typedef unsigned char byte`.

Comment: @the_naive - edit that comment into tour question not as a comment

Comment: @awoodland Is the question any clear to you now? Could you figure out what I should do?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10653499/971127

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
byte bytes[16];
int i=0;
for (;i<16;++i) {
  int value;
  sscanf(etag+2*i,"%02x",&value);
  bytes[i] = value;
}
```

Comment: Copying my answer and using a slightly more complicated function is not fun.

Comment: @H2CO3 - to give him the benefit of the doubt, he only posted a few minutes after you and his answer is is different enough from yours that it would have taken more than three minutes to turn your answer into his, so I don't believe he did copy you. So I've given you both +1. Hope that's some consolation for you.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want to make the 2-letter groups of hex chars to bytes, then store those bytes in your char array. Try this:

```
char *str = "long hex string";

int i;
unsigned char bytes[16];
char tmp[3] = { 0 };
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    memcpy(tmp, str + 2 * i, 2);
    bytes[i] = (unsigned char)strtol(tmp, NULL, 16);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)

below is the example program:

```
/****************************************************************
 *
 * Purpose: To show examples of the strtol function.
 * Author:  M.J. Leslie
 * Date:    06-Nov-94
 *
 ****************************************************************/

#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  char num[10];

                /* Test a valid number      */
  strcpy(num,"13");

  printf("%s(Oct) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL,  8));
  printf("%s(Dec) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 10));
  printf("%s(hex) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 16));

  puts("----------------------------------");

                /* Test a slightly valid number
                 * Returns the same results as 
                 * above.           */
  strcpy(num, "13hzcd");

  printf("%s(Oct) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL,  8));
  printf("%s(Dec) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 10));
  printf("%s(hex) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 16));

  puts("----------------------------------");

                /* Test an invalid number
                 * Returns ZERO         */
  strcpy(num, "hzcd");

  printf("%s(Oct) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL,  8));
  printf("%s(Dec) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 10));
  printf("%s(hex) is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 16));


  puts("----------------------------------");

                /* Test 0 base.
                 * This will look at the number 
                 * and decide the base for its self!
                 */
  strcpy(num, "13");
  printf("%s is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 0));

  strcpy(num, "013");
  printf("%s is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 0));

  strcpy(num, "0x13");
  printf("%s is %i(Dec)\n", num, strtol(num, NULL, 0));

}

/****************************************************************
 *
 * Results of the program:
 *
 *  13(Oct) is 11(Dec)
 *  13(Dec) is 13(Dec)
 *  13(hex) is 19(Dec)
 *  ----------------------------------
 *  13hzcd(Oct) is 11(Dec)
 *  13hzcd(Dec) is 13(Dec)
 *  13hzcd(hex) is 19(Dec)
 *  ----------------------------------
 *  hzcd(Oct) is 0(Dec)
 *  hzcd(Dec) is 0(Dec)
 *  hzcd(hex) is 0(Dec)
 *  ----------------------------------
 *  13 is 13(Dec)
 *  013 is 11(Dec)
 *  0x13 is 19(Dec)
 *
 ****************************************************************/
```

Comment: can you add an example showing how to use it to break down into an array of bytes?