# How to convert a string in hexadecimal string?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ convert string to hexadecimal and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa)

Trying this sample code which I found in StackOverflow...

```
std::string text = "¯"; // AF in HEX ASCII. 
std::ostringstream result;  
result << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::uppercase;  
std::copy(text.begin(), text.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(result, " "));
```

result.str() will be 'FFFFFFAF' instead of just 'AF'

What can I do?

My text can have more than one character, like that: text = '¯ABCÈ'; // AF414243C8
The result after 'convertion' is: FFFFFFAF414243FFFFFFC8.

.

Well, I solved it with a replace... it's not a good practice in this case, but solved.

```
                    if(value > 6)
                    {   //replace
                        std::string& str = stringlist2[count];
                        const std::string& from = "FFFFFF";
                        const std::string& to = "";
                        size_t j;
                        for ( ; (j = stringlist2[count].find( from )) != string::npos ; ) {
                            stringlist2[count].replace( j, from.length(), to );
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Looks like sign extension while converting from `char` to `int` (`0xaf` is more than `0x7f` and is thus negative).

Comment: Yeah, I think Hristo is right. The wrong assumption here is that the character is ASCII-encoded (because ASCII ranges only from `0x0` to `0x7f`)

Comment: It's extended ASCII. http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @GuilhermeQuelhos: There's no such thing as "extended ASCII". You need to specify an encoding if you use more than the standardized 127 character codes (that website mentions that it's ISO-8859-1, but there exist others)

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `unsigned int` to the `operator<<` invoked by
`ostream_iterator`; you're passing a `char`.  Depending on your system,
`char` may be signed or unsigned, and if it is signed and 8 bits (the
most common case), it cannot contain 0xAF (which would be 175).  If the
bit pattern is 0xAF, what it actually contains is -0x51 (or -81).  Which
will be converted to an unsigned by adding it to `UINT_MAX+1`, which
makes for a very large unsigned value.

What you probably need to do is to convert each character to `unsigned
char` first.  This will cause negative values to be converted by adding
`UCHAR_MAX+1`; if you add 0x100 + (0-x51), you'll get 0xAF.  As a
positive value, so when it is converted to `unsigned` (or even to
`int`), it will retain its value.

Typically, when one is doing this sort of thing, it is one character at
a time, and:

```
result << static_cast<int>( static_cast< unsigned char >( ch ) );
```

is used.  (Note the double conversion.)  You could, however, do
something like:

```
std::vector< unsigned char > tmp( text.begin(), text.end() );
```

and use your call to copy on `tmp`.  Or use `std::transform`:

```
struct ToUnsignedChar
{
    unsigned char operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned char>( ch );
    }
};

std::transform( 
    text.begin(),
    text.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>( result, " " ),
    ToUnsignedChar() );
```

(This would be a good candidate for a lambda if you have C++11.)