# How to convert string into hex value

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert string value into its hex form, but not able to do.
Following is the C++ code snippet, with which I am trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string>
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string hexstr;
    hexstr = "000005F5E101";
    uint64_t Value;
    sscanf(hexstr.c_str(), "%" PRIu64 "", &Value);
    printf("value = %" PRIu64 " \n", Value);

    return 0;
}
```

The Output is only 5, which is not correct.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're writing C++, why would you even consider using `sscanf` and `printf`? Avoid the pain and just use a `stringstream`:

```
int main() { 

    std::istringstream buffer("000005F5E101");

    unsigned long long value;

    buffer >> std::hex >> value;

    std::cout << std::hex << value;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string myString = "45";
  istringstream buffer(myString);
  uint64_t value;
  buffer >> std::hex >> value;

  return 0;
}
```