# How to retrieve byte values in hex format from a string with c++?

Tags: c++

I am working on a project where i use a RFID reader/writer (cr500)

I got a problem on how to convert my string `"FFFFFFFFFFFF"` to `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"`

from

```
string key = "FFFFFFFFFFFF";
```

to

```
string raw = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
```

How can this be solved using c++ standard library funcions?

Comment: All you need is to convert a string representing hex bytes into the represented byte array. Google knows how to do it.

Comment: Is this really a string-to-string question, or do you perhaps want the integer value that the string specifies?

Comment: You can't convert a literal string. You have to make another one.

Comment: **−1** Not real code.

Comment: You've had too much exposure to dynamically typed languages. C++ is statically typed, and a `std::string` is no longer your one-size-fits-all data type. I'm somewhat convinced, that this question is the result of starting out with the wrong data type.

Comment: Welcome to SO, where there is no such thing as bad qu.. oh wait, actually there is. But even so, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738023/1460794) for a possible answer to your question.

Comment: but how to send the key to the device. when i am using "\xFF.." it's work perfectly but not with "FFF..."

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i used it permanently. but i want to read it from a gui and how to convert it

Comment: Well it looks trivial at first hand but actually isn't using standard functions.

Comment: Be careful what you ask for.  What do you expect if the key value equals "000000000000" (or any 2 digit hex number with a byte value of `'\x00'`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll take your question literally and concentrate on how to convert from the character literal `"FFFFFFFFFFFF"` to the target literals value of `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"` as you're asking for (pun intended).

Here's one way <sup>1</sup> to achieve what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "FFFFFFFFFFFF"; // << Let's suppose this is given from the GUI
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    std::string output;
    std::string sbyte;
    while(iss >> std::setw(2) >> sbyte) {
        std::cout << sbyte << std::endl;
        std::istringstream iss2(sbyte);
        unsigned u;
        iss2 >> std::hex >> u;
        output += (unsigned char)u;
    }

    // std::string::data() contains the resulting byte values:
    for(unsigned char x : output) {
        std::cout << std::hex << "\\x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
                  << (unsigned)x; 
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
FF
FF
FF
FF
FF
FF
\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff
```

See [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b28e5a3fb309ff6)

You can control the input field width using [`std::setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) as shown above.

---

**Note:**

This apparently works with `std::string`, but not using `unsigned u;` directly with a former `std::setw(2)` directive:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "FFFFFFFFFFFF";
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    std::string output;
    unsigned u;
    while(iss >> std::setw(2) >> std::hex >> u) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') <<  u << std::endl;
        output += (unsigned char)u;
    }

    for(unsigned char x : output) {
        std::cout << std::hex << "\\x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
                  << (unsigned)x; 
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62f368eb25032c8e)

---

<sub>1. You can also split up your input string using [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) in a loop.</sub>

Comment: thank u a lot. and i think a solution:
    std::string key="";
    for(int i=0;i<input.size();i=i+2){
        key=key+"\\x"+input.substr(i,2);
    }