# Comparison of string with the File data

Tags: c++

I m currently stuck in a very simple problem ,this code is part of my programme it takes data from the user and then reads the data from the file(that contains the name of the movies and actors) and compare it with input but it gives wrong result.This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    string compare;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("movie.txt");
    bool found = false;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, compare))
        {
            if (compare == name)
            {
                cout << "record found" << endl;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    if (found)
        cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example user input and an example line from the file being checked?

Comment: None of the usual howlers in the code. Only problem I can spot right off is not opening the file outputs "not found". Probably should handle that with an else and a `cout << "file not open" <<endl;` to make sure the file really did open.

Comment: first line of the file contains name Bilitis (1977) , if the user enters the same name the output should be record found but it wont.@ShadowRanger

Comment: i checked it and also what is present in compare  variable and name it gives same output but on comparison dont give right result.@user4581301

Answer (score 0):

For debug you can use `string_to_hex` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa) on both `compare` and `name`

Comment: Recommend expanding on that because right now what you suggest makes no sense.