# std::hex and std::setw not working with some characters

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, hex

What I'm trying to do is converting a string's bytes into hexadecimal format.
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382894/878711) (and many others consistent) I've tried the code:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
   std::string inputText = u8"A7°";

   std::stringstream ss;
   // print every char of the string as hex on 2 values
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputText.size (); ++i)
   {
      ss << std::hex << std::setfill ('0') << std::setw (2) << (int) inputText[i];
   }

   std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

but with some characters coded in UTF 8 it does't work.
For Instance, in strings containing the degrees symbol ( ° ) coded in UTF8, the result is: `ffffffc2ffffffb0` instead of `c2b0`.
Now I would expect the algorithm to work on individual bytes regardless of their contents and furthermore the result seems to ignore the `setw(2)` parameter.
Why does I get such a result?

(run test program [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BkNu5ipYS))

Comment: Post the smallest complete program you can write that compiles, runs, and shows the problem. It should only need about six lines of code. Note that negative values generally have all their high bits set to 1, which in hex shows up as a string of `f`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Pete Becker already hinted in a comment, converting a negative value to a larger integer fills the higher bits with '1'. The solution is to first cast the `char` to `unsigned char` before casting it to `int`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string inputText = "-12°C";
    // print every char of the string as hex on 2 values
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputText.size(); ++i)
    {
       std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0')  
                 << std::setw(2) << (int)(unsigned char)inputText[i];
    }
}
```

`setw` sets the *minimal* width, it does not truncate longer values.