# How to convert a std::string to UTF-8 encoded string in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a std::string - INPUT - "(#1476710203) éf.pdf"

I want the result as - OUTPUT - "UTF-8 "%28#1476710203%29%20%C3%A9f.pdf"

I have tried

1. std::codecvt_utf8
2. Win32 MultiByteToWideChar() function to convert data from CP437 to UTF-16, and then use the WideCharToMultiByte() function to convert data from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

But, when I print the bytes in after both conversions, it still shows input string while I want the output string.

Comment: That just looks like normal URL-encoding. For which there are plenty of solutions, tutorials and examples to be found in a multitude of languages all over the Internet.

Comment: Also take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Don't forget how to create a [mre] of your own attempt, or how to [edit] your question. And don't spam tags.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have gone through all, but they don't print the Out put I want, can you help me how to do that

Comment: It looks like the UTF-8 conversion is step 1, followed by URL-encoding. `%C3%A9` is that é in UTF-8. But you don't mention what you're converting _from_. `std::string` doesn't care, it just holds `char` without caring a whole lot about the meaning.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah %C3%A9 is é in UTF-8. I am converting from any characters that can be given from here https://www.utf8-chartable.de/ to its equivalent UTF-8 also given in that chart.

Comment: But `%28` - `(` is ascii, why did you also convert it in the sample?

Comment: Begin with something like `std::string destination; for (auto it = begin(source); it != end(source); ++it) { if (std::isalnum(*it)) { destination += *it; } else { destination += '%'; destination += char_to_hex(*it); } }` Implement the `char_to_hex` function. Add more cases to handle special characters (like `'#'` which seems to be copied as-is). And of course detection of [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded characters. (Note the bit-pattern of the [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding))

Comment: @thedemons: `(` is also in UTF-8 (_everything_ is in UTF-8, it's a full Unicode encoding). It's converted in step 2, as part of URL-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to parse the UTF-8 characters in the string in order not to encode the whole string, this code was taken from [Dear ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/f6bd7c8e53b541dfd6ab22d2684b7c8005a579e4/imgui.cpp#L1954) with a bit of modifications:

```cpp
int WideCharFromUtf8(unsigned int* out_char, const char* in_text, const char* in_text_end)
{
    const char lengths[32] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0 };
    const int masks[] = { 0x00, 0x7f, 0x1f, 0x0f, 0x07 };
    const uint32_t mins[] = { 0x400000, 0, 0x80, 0x800, 0x10000 };
    const int shiftc[] = { 0, 18, 12, 6, 0 };
    const int shifte[] = { 0, 6, 4, 2, 0 };
    int len = lengths[*(const unsigned char*)in_text >> 3];
    int wanted = len + (!len ? 1 : 0);

    if (in_text_end == NULL)
        in_text_end = in_text + wanted; // Max length, nulls will be taken into account.

    // Copy at most 'len' bytes, stop copying at 0 or past in_text_end. Branch predictor does a good job here,
    // so it is fast even with excessive branching.
    unsigned char s[4];
    s[0] = in_text + 0 < in_text_end ? in_text[0] : 0;
    s[1] = in_text + 1 < in_text_end ? in_text[1] : 0;
    s[2] = in_text + 2 < in_text_end ? in_text[2] : 0;
    s[3] = in_text + 3 < in_text_end ? in_text[3] : 0;

    // Assume a four-byte character and load four bytes. Unused bits are shifted out.
    *out_char = (uint32_t)(s[0] & masks[len]) << 18;
    *out_char |= (uint32_t)(s[1] & 0x3f) << 12;
    *out_char |= (uint32_t)(s[2] & 0x3f) << 6;
    *out_char |= (uint32_t)(s[3] & 0x3f) << 0;
    *out_char >>= shiftc[len];

    // Accumulate the various error conditions.
    int e = 0;
    e = (*out_char < mins[len]) << 6; // non-canonical encoding
    e |= ((*out_char >> 11) == 0x1b) << 7;  // surrogate half?
    e |= (*out_char > 0x10FFFF) << 8;  // out of range?
    e |= (s[1] & 0xc0) >> 2;
    e |= (s[2] & 0xc0) >> 4;
    e |= (s[3]) >> 6;
    e ^= 0x2a; // top two bits of each tail byte correct?
    e >>= shifte[len];

    if (e)
    {
        // No bytes are consumed when *in_text == 0 || in_text == in_text_end.
        // One byte is consumed in case of invalid first byte of in_text.
        // All available bytes (at most `len` bytes) are consumed on incomplete/invalid second to last bytes.
        // Invalid or incomplete input may consume less bytes than wanted, therefore every byte has to be inspected in s.
        int cmp = !!s[0] + !!s[1] + !!s[2] + !!s[3];
        wanted = wanted < cmp ? wanted : cmp;
        *out_char = 0xFFFD;
    }

    return wanted;
}
```

Then loop through the string and encode the character if it is UTF-8:

```cpp
void main()
{
    std::string utf8_string(u8"(#1476710203) éf.pdf");
    std::string result;

    result.reserve(utf8_string.size());

    const char* text_begin = utf8_string.c_str();
    const char* text_end = text_begin + utf8_string.size();

    for (const char* cursor = text_begin; cursor < text_end;)
    {
        unsigned int wide_char = *cursor;

        // this is an ascii char
        if (wide_char < 0x80)
        {
            result.push_back(*cursor);
            cursor += 1;
        }
        // this is an utf-8 char
        else
        {
            size_t utf8_len = WideCharFromUtf8(&wide_char, cursor, text_end);

            if (wide_char == 0) // Malformed UTF-8?
                break;

            result += FormatUtf8(cursor, utf8_len);
            cursor += utf8_len;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", result.c_str());
}
```

And the `FormatUtf8` function, converting string to hex string was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382894/13253010):

```cpp
// convert array of char to hex, thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382894/13253010
std::string FormatUtf8(const char* text, size_t size)
{
    const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    std::string output;
    output.reserve(size * 3);

    for (const char* cursor = text; cursor < text + size; cursor++)
    {
        unsigned char chr = *cursor;
        output.push_back('%');
        output.push_back(hex_digits[chr >> 4]);
        output.push_back(hex_digits[chr & 15]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

The output:

```
(#1476710203) %C3%A9f.pdf
```

This should be enough to solve the problem, as you asked for encoding UTF-8 and not URL, processing the other URL-encoded characters will be too long to put in an answer.